# Run an executable when a web address is called

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to find a way to run a dos executable when called by another server.
It's hard to explain sorry,

So I have a windows server 2008r2.  On it is a dos exe that I need to run.
I also have a linux ubuntu server that hosts some SQL and web pages (apache).

Users update a table in the linux box, and when they do I need to run a dos exe on the windows box.

I don't want to use scheduled tasks on the windows box, because updates need to happen at the moment the data is changed in the linux box with little delay.

Any way anyone can think of that the linux box can 'call' the windows server to run the exe?

Thanks :)

Comment: Expose it as a web API (which is what I believe your title was alluding to anyway; if so, what's your specific question?)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to code up a web server that responds only to connections from the linux box's IP, and runs the exe when a certain page is POSTed to.

Comment: Perfect solution, and I know that's what I'm after.  But how to do that?  Can it be done with IIS in server 2008?   I know I can restrict access to the linux box's ip, but the question I can't find the answer to is, how to have it run the exe.

Comment: Yeah why not? For example in C# you would just use `Process.Start`.